# JSF 2.0 internationalization without faces-config

Tags: java, jsf, internationalization, jsf-2

I want to provide different languages in my jsf-application.

I've found [that](http://www.javabeat.net/tips/102-implement-internationalization-and-localizati.html) explanation and I wonder if I can also do that without faces-config (because I don't use one since jsf2 has annotations).

Can I do it another way? Or do I have to create a faces-config.xml ?

Thank you for help :-)
cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a minimal `faces-config.xml` holding few conf related to i18n and go ahead also have a look at [jsf-2-internationalization-example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-internationalization-example/)

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that you cannot avoid faces-config.xml. However, that is not such a big deal.

If you are using Eclipse you can install [JBoss Tools](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/apachesolr_search/jboss%20tools). Then you can simply right click with your mouse on a project -> Configure -> Add JSF capabilities. It will allow you to easy externalize strings from your JSF page - simply select string that you want to be localized, right click and choose "Externalize Strings...". It will allow you to set up (create) properties file automatically. It also suggest translation variable and resource key while you type, very nice feature.